# How would one classify a ring oscillator?

Tags: oscillator

This may be obvious to some, but how would one classify a ring oscillator (see figure below of a ring oscillator)? For example, the Wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator, has the ring oscillator under the relaxation oscillator heading. I would have thought a ring oscillator is more like a simple feedback oscillator where two of the gates can be merged and considered the amplifier and the third gate the feedback component. For a relaxation oscillator, I thought one needed a component that could be charged and repeatedly discharged by feedback? Any comments on this?

[image]

Comment: That looks like someone just plopped that line on the wiki page.  Ring osc. work on delays, not caps and inductors charging and discharging.

Comment: The Ring_Oscillator page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator doesn't mention relaxation at all.

Comment: Correct, the ring oscillator page doesn't mention relaxation oscillators at all. Looks like the authors weren't sure how to classify ring oscillators on the oscillator page. Hence, I am curious how readers of this question might classify it.

Comment: I remember reading about ring oscillators from articles dating to WW II!! Then, they used tubes with tuned coax lines between sections in order to help isolate mutual inductance and capacitance loading effects so they could increase the oscillation frequency. (Back then, getting over 300 MHz was "difficult," otherwise.) And they used the name "ring oscillator" at that time. (They used an ***even*** number of triodes, by the way.) I've always considered them to be a subset of relaxation oscillators. It shall be interesting to see folks place proper boundaries on the term here.

Comment: I'm interested in your reasons for considering them a subset of relaxation oscillators?

Comment: I have always considered them to be a variety of phase shift oscillator. Don't know if there is an official ruling.

Comment: @rhody In some cases, one finds "natural boundaries" for definitions -- those that nature shows us and we don't arbitrarily impose -- such as the five to six orders of magnitude difference in one measure that separates Pluto from the other eight planets (so far) identified in our solar system. In other cases, it's just arbitrary and there's little to be said different from stuff inside and stuff outside the lines. Since I'm a hobbyist, I'd rather listen to what EEs say. I'll know if I hear better definitions (the 5-order distinction) and perhaps learn. I may speak if no one else does, though.

Comment: @rhody However, I'd like to see anyone's definitional boundaries include the original use of the term "ring oscillator." If it fails on that account, then I have good question for those making the definitions. In the earliest use of the term, 1/4 wavelength resonances were recognized to yield very high Q. In that original usage, these were coordinated to produce a "ring" of 1/4 wavelength standing voltage waves that invert the voltage. But I have a different thought regarding the natural, fundamental frequency of a system. Still, as I said, I'd very much like to learn from EEs on this. +1.

Comment: Why do we need at least three (and an uneven number of) units?  Answer: Because of negative feedback for DC and 360 deg phase shift (pos. fedback) for the oscillation frequency. These are typical requirements for all kinds of phase-shift oscillators.

Comment: @LvW I think your comment has helped. In my mind, I mixed up the phase shift with the 180-degree signal inversion that each unit produces. Three units yield a net 180 inversion of the signal but in the frequency domain, the signal is still shifted up to 270 degrees (90 degrees per unit), plus a net inversion of 180 yields the potential to shift by 360. In that case it's acting like a phase-shift oscillator. This will also explain why a two-unit ring with one inverter and one follow-through unit won't oscillate which I've also been puzzled by.  Is my logic ok on this?

Comment: @rhody I found an article (a lot less difficult to find than I had earlier imagined, using google) that appears closer to my recollections. Take a look at Figure 3 in this: ["Ring Oscillators for U.H.F. Transmission," January 1947, Radio News](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/radio-news/ring-oscillators-uhf-transmission-radio-news-january-1947.htm).

Comment: @jonk What a strange-looking beast, not seen one of these before. I'm not sure how that works, I don't quite understand their explanation, Fig 4 looks interesting. This video also shows a very long transistor based ring oscillator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVCW2A0C68A

Comment: @rhody....a small correction of your calculation: net 180 deg for DC (three times inversion) and another 180 deg for one frequency only (60 deg. per unit) caused by the delay of each unit.

Comment: @rhody I'm still waiting to see an EE provide the "what's included" and the "what's not included" boundary conditions that define "ring oscillator" while keeping in mind the original invention and early use of the phrase and also preserving modern usage, as well. It shall be a joy to watch and, if someone does a yeoman's job of it, I will definitely learn something!

Comment: @jonk I'm not sure how the ring oscillator you found works but it's possible that the modern meaning of the phrase 'ring oscillator' has changed and now refers to simply three inverters (or an odd number) in a ring.

Comment: @LvW Got it, thanks. Makes sense now.

Comment: @rhody It's based upon the idea that a quarter-wavelength stretch inverts the voltage. Which is an "inverter." I get it that you don' t follow that usage. But your ignorance (and I don't mean that in any negative way, it's just a statement of fact you've made about that circuit) shouldn't be taken to then justify re-interpretation to exclude it. I think a well-informed modern definition will very likely include that incarnation and will be... well... well-informed.