# Oscillators shouldn't work

Tags: analog, oscillator, feedback, positive-feedback

The Barkhausen criteria for sustaining oscillations states that the total phase around the loop must be 0 and the gain must be unity. I was thinking about this and got stuck :) The aforementioned criteria is most commonly explained as "at least the signal must not get smaller while travelling around the loop" so if these two conditions are met then it enhances itself. But doesn't it mean that the signal will continue growing until it hits one of the supply rails?

Comment: Maybe have a look at logic gate ring oscillators: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/467055/223146. Lots of oscillator questions and answers here!

Comment: I think you are considering all frequencies to be amplified around the loop, including DC. To make an oscillator, you need amplification at a particular frequency. Positive feedback at DC can indeed cause driving to one of the rails and staying there.

Comment: The Barkhausen criteria applies when the loop gain is _exactly_ 1. Not more, not less. This loop gain depends on the frequency, and the loop gain will be 1 at the oscillation frequency.

Comment: Indeed an oscillator is designed to be used at some predefined frequencies, and most certainly not at dc. My main concern is the fact that it oscillates, I mean why does the output signal change its direction, what's the forcing driving it to go in the opposite direction?

Comment: Regarding the oscillators made with logic gates: the funny thing is that, for example for the ring oscillator, that the signal starting at the input of the inverter, and the signal coming back to the same input after travelling the loop are complements, which puzzles me too.

Comment: The frequency domain behavior of the oscillator is clear: the signals continue to build up in a certain frequency until some sort of control mechanism (maybe nonlinear behavior of the active circuitry)  forces them to stabilize. Thinking about the time domain signal, ask yourself this: why does the sine wave change its direction? You have to consider time domain differential equations and solve them for the oscillator case. This will solve the mystery of the cyclic behavior. (For linear approximations,  this will be identical to solving the circuit in the frequency domain)

Answer (score 1):

> *But doesn't it mean that the signal will continue growing until it
>   hits one of the supply rails?*

Yes, it’s a common problem in some oscillators e.g. the Wien bridge or phase shift oscillator and, the output amplitude can hit rail to rail proportions but then it will stabilise. Quite often you see special add-on circuits to the original “theoretical” circuits that stabilise amplitude and give remarkably good quality sine waves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am mostly confused by the fact that the signal isn't constantly growing or decaying, but it changes its direction. Is it because of the intrinsic noise of the circuit? If so, is it theoretically possible in some ideal world to build an oscillator based on completely noiseless elements?

Comment: Changes its direction? Your question didn’t raise that issue (whatever it means).

Comment: I apologize for the tautology, but to be able to clarify my (possibly dumb) question, I want to ask another one: Is it possible to build an oscillator using ideally noiseless components?

Comment: Tautology? I didn’t notice one and no, you can’t build an oscillator using noiseless components. You can in a simulator of course but, noise has got nothing to do with an oscillators waveform shape if it’s the shape you refer to. If you keep changing your questions direction I shall be confused (more than I am now).

Comment: So to sum up, an oscillator is built using an amplifier in a positive feedback loop. Due to the fact that Barkhausen criteria can be satisfied only for some nonzero frequency, the noise component of the circuit will continue regenerating untill the loop gain drops to unity, after which the oscillations will be sustained. In a theoretical world, where noiseless components exist and the circuit is put in a noiseless environment, oscillations aren't possible, as there is nothing to be amplified. The shape of the oscillators waveform is defined by the filtering action in the circuit. Am I right?

Comment: @BranTran - it doesn't have to be that oscillation builds up from noise; it can be any disturbance. For simulation it is often necessary to inject a transient into the circuit. IN the real world a power on surge can often do that.

Comment: @KevinWhite does if the disturbance is lower in frequency than that for which the oscillator is tuned, will it fade out or will it somehow rise in frequency?

Comment: A singular disturbance possesses all frequencies and hence, is a good and usual candidate for kicking off an oscillator, much more so than measly noise levels. A power up disturbance is massively more disturbing than noise.